# Mongoose - Modify post find result

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, middleware

I want to modify the result in a `schema.post('find')' middleware, but this seems impossible:

```
const PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String })

PersonSchema.post('find', function(result) {
    console.log('HOOW: Post Find', result)
    result.team("Real Madrid")
    return result

})

const Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema)
```

Whenever I try to perform a find query, the console.log statement is executed but, the `team` field never gets added.

How can I add this field to my result?

**NOTE:**

My real code is a bit more complex, I need to make some queries to the database and add those results to the result of the `find` query.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the results of `find` in a `post` hook if you edit the array in place using things like `Array.splice` or other in-place array modifiers. However, to restructure the results themselves (for instance, converting the `results` array to an object so you can add top-level properties), you must use `ovewriteMiddlewareResult()`.

See this PR for Mongoose: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/pull/11927

Also see documentation for `overwriteMiddlewareResult()`: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-overwriteMiddlewareResult

If you need to add a top-level property to the results, you'll need to first convert it to an object, then use `overwriteMiddlewareResult()` when you return it::

```js
PersonSchema.post('find', function(result) {
    result = { team: 'Madrid', result };
    return mongoose.overwriteMiddlewareResult(result);
})
```

But if you are okay adding the `team` property to each individual result (each array element), then something similar to the previous solutions will work by editing the array in-place like so:

```js
PersonSchema.post('find', function(result) {
    result.forEach(elem => elem.team = 'Madrid');
})
```

Hope this helps clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in  `result.team("Real Madrid")`

change to

```
result.team="Real Madrid"
```

or

```
result['team']="Real Madrid"     (Quotes are required)
```

try this

```
PersonSchema.post('find', function(result) {
        console.log('HOOW: Post Find', result)
        result.team="Real Madrid"
        return result

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

To add additional field to documents returned from query, you may use [lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-lean):

```
Person.find({...}).lean();
```

And because result of `find()` method is an array so you need to loop through it and add field to each element:

```
PersonSchema.post('find', function(result) {
  console.log('HOOW: Post Find', result)
  result.forEach(val => val.team="Real Madrid");
  return result
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this

```
PersonSchema.post('find', function(result) {

    result= result.toObject();

    console.log('HOOW: Post Find', result)
    result.team("Real Madrid")
    return result
})
```